# How to have dynamic value within contentful?

Tags: contentful

I am looking to be able to hold a value in a variable and use that variable throughout contentful, is this possible? Let’s say the variable is a number 12345, this number may change a month from now. If I write 12345 inside each content area like 60 times, I have to edit 60 times (not even mentioning locales). Is there a way I can create a label and put this value in that and use that label throughout my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case I would suggest creating a separate content type that holds this value. You can then refer to this value in any other content types. This way, if you have to change the value, you only do it once, and all the other content types have the new value.